# Unknown provider: {0} angularjs call a service

Tags: angularjs, service

i get the error "Unknown provider: {0}", if i try to call a service of the submodule inside the submodule

here the mainModule script

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", ["categoriesApp","ui.router"]);

//a service in the mainmodule which i can call with no problems in the submodule
mainApp.factory("getDataSvc", ["$http", "$q", "path", function ($http, $q, path) {
  return{
    ...
    some $http
    ....
}]);
```

and now the submodule

```
var categoriesApp = angular.module("categoriesApp", []);

//i can inject and use getDataSvc with no problems from the mainmodule
categoriesApp.controller("listCtrl", ["$scope", "getDataSvc", function ($scope, getDataSvc){
  getDataSvc.categories().then(function(data){
    ...
  })
}])

//my service in the submodule
categoriesApp.factory("sharedDataSvc", ["$scope", function ($scope){
  return{
    getValue: function(){
      return "oioioioi";
    }
  }
}])

//in this line i get the error, if i try to inject the sharedDataSvc  
//if i dont inject it, i get no errors, but cant use the service ;)
categoriesApp.controller("addBtnCrtl", ["$scope", "sharedDataSvc", function ($scope, sharedDataSvc){
  console.log(sharedDataSvc.getValue());
}])
```

hope somebody can tell me what i`m doing wrong ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The problem is with `sharedDataSvc` factory

You cannot inject `$scope` to a factory because `$scope` is not a registered provider.
$scope is only injected to controllers ( within a locals object ).

```
categoriesApp.factory("sharedDataSvc", [ function (){
  return{
    getValue: function(){
      return "oioioioi";
    }
  }
}])
```

- each controller may be instantiated multiple time ( with each instance $scope is a different scope)
- each service is instantiated only once and then cached ( the same instance injected everywhere)

Comment: thank you ;) i dont know how many times i read the line, but i overlooked everytime the $scope ;)